# How to pass parameter for build-in commands in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to pass some parameters through `xargs`, but as some bash commands like `cd`, `wait` are build-in commands, `xargs` can't find them, so how can I pass the parameter to these commands?

For example, I expect this script to output `ls` results 60s later:

```
sleep 60 &
pgrep sleep | wait;
ls
```

But `wait` seems can't receive the pid, because I tried `pgrep sleep | echo` and prints nothing, so the script displays the `ls` result immediately without waiting.

Comment: You don't need pgrep here. Just do `wait $!`

Comment: Have you considered `wait $(pgrep sleep)` or something like that?

Comment: `wait` doesn't get its parameter from standard input, it gets it from the command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
sleep 60 && ls
```

Comment: This *is* an attempt to answer the question so recommending deletion is not the right course of action.